# bulk import of xml data in to sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012, bulk-import

I have a set of xml files that I want to parse the data of and import in to a sql server 2012 database. The provided xml files will be validated against a schema.

I am looking as to what is the best method of doing this is. I have found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171878.aspx

I am wondering if this is the best way or if there are others?

Comment: You could use the ssis xml file connection in a data flow

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. SSIS XML Source. This does *not* validate against the schema. If you want to detect and properly handle invalid XML files, create a script task to validate the schema in C#.
2. Parse the XML in a stored procedure.

   - Insert the entire XML file in one column. Depending on your schema validation requirements, you can use an untyped or typed XML column. (Or both)
   - Parse the XML using XPath functions. This is actually very fast.

```
    INSERT INTO SomeTable (Column1, Column2, Column3)
    SELECT
        YourXmlColumn.value('(/root/col1)[1]','int'),
        YourXmlColumn.value('(/root/col2)[1]','nvarchar(10)'),
        YourXmlColumn.value('(/root/col3)[1]','nvarchar(2000)'),
        YourXmlColumn.value('(/root/col4)[1]','datetime2(0)')
    FROM YourXmlTable
```